# Emacs in PuTTY with xterm-mouse-mode: how to paste?

Tags: terminal-emacs, mouse

I'm running Emacs under PuTTY and this works better then I expected.
But since I sometimes use the mouse to focus the PuTTY window, I turned xterm-mouse-mode on. This way the focus in the text changes to where I click.

But now I can't past text into putty anymore.
Normally this is done by a right click and then putty sends the copied text.
But now Emacs receives a `mouse-3` event first.

Is it possible to map `mouse-3` to something so that the text after the mouse event is pasted to Emacs?

Here is my current config: https://github.com/r03/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/init.el

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If [mouse reporting](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-features-mouse) is on, then Shift+click is still interpreted by the terminal and not passed to the application. Thus, if a right-click pastes outside Emacs, and a straight right-click is passed through to Emacs, then Shift+right-click should paste in Emacs.

[Passthrough of Shift+click can be disabled](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-mouseshift), check that it's enabled.

This applies to PuTTY and many other terminal emulators. (I think they all follow suit from xterm, as is often the case.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about shift+right-click. Works perfect.